# Paypal error: Timeout processing request

Tags: asp.net, paypal, runtime-error

I'm using Paypal_base.dll to process Paypal transactions in my asp.net website but I'm getting errors. My code looks like:

```
 string Response;
    const string paymentAction = "Sale";
    const string currency = "USD";

    var caller = new NVPCallerServices();
    IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();

    profile.APIUsername = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIUsername"];
    profile.APIPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIPassword"];
    profile.APISignature = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["token"];

    profile.Environment= "SandBox";
    caller.APIProfile = profile;

    var encoder = new NVPCodec();
    encoder["VERSION"] = "58.0";
    encoder["METHOD"] = "DoDirectPayment";
    encoder["PAYMENTACTION"] = paymentAction;
    encoder["AMT"] = amount;
    encoder["CREDITCARDTYPE"] = creditCardType;
    encoder["ACCT"] = creditCardNumber;
    encoder["EXPDATE"] = expdateMonth;
   // encoder["CVV2"] = cvv2Number;
   // encoder["FIRSTNAME"] = firstName;
   // encoder["LASTNAME"] = lastName;
   // encoder["STREET"] = city + ", " + state + ", " + countryCode;
   // encoder["CITY"] = city;
   // encoder["STATE"] = state;
   // encoder["ZIP"] = zip;
    encoder["COUNTRYCODE"] = countryCode;
    encoder["CURRENCYCODE"] = currency;

    // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
    string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
    string pStresponsenvp = caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp);

    var decoder = new NVPCodec();
    decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
    Response = decoder["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
    if (decoder["ACK"] == "Success")
    {
    }
    return decoder["ACK"];
```

The value at 
Response = decoder["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]; 
is "Timeout processing request"

and decoder["ACK"] gives "Failure" message.

**caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp) has this value:**

TIMESTAMP=2013%2d10%2d02T22%3a40%3a04Z&CORRELATIONID=fa19cc06164da&ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=10001&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Internal%20Error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Timeout%20processing%20request

Comment: FWIW, `ACK` can also be `SuccessWithWarning`... What is the error code? L_ERRORCODE0?

Comment: decoder["L_ERRORCODE0"] is "10001"